# How to create a sort features In Drupal?

Tags: users

I'm new to Drupal and want to create a sort option (to sort some Forum topics) so that a user can select any topic and apply it.

Here is an image to better illustrate this:

[image]

How to make such sort option?

Answer (score 0):

Use [advanced_forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module. 
See the image attached, it provides sort option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the **tabular** display by using the [DataTables](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) **module**, which uses the [datatables](http://datatables.net/) **plugin**.

In doing so, you get all the typical dataTables widgets available, such as sorting for appropriate columns, but also a search box, pagination, etc.

Comment: Just curious if you have any feedback to share after my suggested answer ...